# Dynamically Invoke A Method, Given only Strings with Method Name c# Resources file

Tags: c#, resource-files

I have my file Resources and I make my call like that :

```
string valueOfResource = namespaceName.Resources.nameOfString;
```

and now I do

```
string nameOfString = "Name_Res";
string buildstring = "namespaceName.Resources." + nameOfString;
```

And I need to get a value of buildstring into another string :

I want to get:

```
string valueOfResource = namespaceName.Resources.Name_Res;
```

and I have :

```
string valueOfResource = buildstring;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help

[ResourceManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

> The ResourceManager class retrieves resources from a binary .resources
>   file that is embedded in an assembly or from a standalone .resources
>   file

```
var myManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(MyResource));
var myString = myManager.GetString("StringKey");
```

Comment: I have an error when I do it : "Can not find appropriate resources for the specified culture or neutral culture. Make sure \ "TestNamespace.Ressources.resources \" has been correctly embedded or linked in the assembly"

Comment: It work finally thx, I entered the wrong name if MyResource (ConsoleApp1.Properties.Ressources is correct)

Comment: @ElzbietaIgual glad to help